# Fulltext search in layered navigation page

Tags: layered-navigation, search, magento-2.1.7, fulltext

if we pass a query string in the `/catalogsearch/result?q=string` page it will return products which match the string with any of its attributes. But in the filter navigation search result page, we can't pass query string like this. After a long research I found there is a fulltext search performs in the former case. My question is, can we implement this search in the layered navigation page like `/tops-men/jackets-men.html?q=red&style_general=118`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you consider third-party module?

Answer (score 0):

For that, I think, you just need your attributes (eg. `style_general`) set to yes for `Use in Search Results Layered Navigation`.  You could find this in Stores > Attributes > Product > [attribute] > Storefront Properties.

Maybe you would have to clear cache.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it is coming perfectly in this page : /catalogsearch/result. but I need to implement this query string full text search in layered navigation page. You can see that is not working there by default

Comment: Well, catalog search result page is a layered navigation page :)

Comment: You can filtered on attributes by setting Yes to `Use in Layered Navigation`. But if you need query string search in others layered navigation page, like in category page, it will be dreadfully hard...

Comment: yeah that is i need to acheive